# Can alpha radiation make other materials radioactive?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

Most general sources that describe the basics of ionizing radiation assert that the only type of radiation that can directly make other materials radioactive is neutron radiation (via "neutron activation").

Googling "does radiation make things radioactive?" produces a few examples, for instance, [from the Nuclear Regulatory Commission](https://www.nrc.gov/about-nrc/radiation/health-effects/radiation-basics.html):

> Of the five types of ionizing radiation discussed here, neutrons are
> the only one that can make objects radioactive.

Or from [this "Ask the Experts" answer from the Health Physics Society](https://hps.org/publicinformation/ate/q12968.html):

> For most radiations that people, especially laypeople, encounter,
> which would include x rays, gamma radiation, beta particles, and alpha
> particles, the exposure of the people or objects to the radiation does
> not produce any radioactivity within them.
>
> [...]
>
> There is one radiation, well-known but less common than those
> mentioned above, that is capable of inducing radioactivity in an
> irradiated person or object; that is neutron radiation. The reason
> that neutrons are effective in that regard and other radiations are
> not is because radioactivity is a property of the nucleus of an atom,
> and the common x, gamma, beta, and alpha radiations interact with the
> electrons of atoms, but not within the nuclei, whereas neutrons are
> able to penetrate the electron cloud around an atom and be absorbed by
> the nucleus, changing the nuclear configuration and, in some cases,
> making it unstable against radioactive decay. For example, if a person
> is exposed to significant neutron radiation, one of the most notable
> radioactive products that we would expect to be produced would be <sup>24</sup>Na
> (sodium-24), produced when stable <sup>23</sup>Na captures a neutron. Sodium is a
> relatively abundant element in the body and is readily activated to
> the <sup>24</sup>Na product. Similarly, many other materials, especially metals,
> are subject to neutron activation.

However, I am reading *The Making of the Atomic Bomb* by Richard Rhodes and just came across the description of the experiment (p. 201) which won Irène and Frédéric Joliot-Curie the 1935 Nobel Prize in Chemistry, in which they discovered that aluminum bombarded with alpha particles produced a radioactive isotope of phosphorus (<sup>30</sup>P):
$$^{27}\text{Al} + \alpha \rightarrow ^{30}\text{P} + \text{n}$$
The <sup>30</sup>P is unstable and decays to <sup>30</sup>Si via positron emission with a half life of about 2.5 minutes.

Although a neutron is emitted here (which could conceivably go on to cause neutron activation), from the description it seems like it is the capture of the alpha particle by the aluminum atom which directly causes the production of the unstable (radioactive) <sup>30</sup>P.

This seems to imply that if I had an alpha source and some aluminum foil, the aluminum foil itself would become somewhat radioactive from exposure to the alpha source because it actually now contains a small amount of radioactive <sup>30</sup>P.

Are the assertions made by the NRC and HPS that non-neutron radiation (specifically alpha radiation in this case) cannot induce radioactivity simply wrong? Or is there some subtlety that I'm missing?

Even [the Wikipedia article on Induced radioactivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_radioactivity) explains how it was discovered by the Joliot-Curies with their alpha particle + aluminum experiment but then goes on to explain that neutron activation is the main form of induced radioactivity, with photodisintegration (via high-energy gamma rays) as a less common form, with no mention at all of alpha-particle induced radioactivity.

So, what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You really aren't missing anything. Yes, one can do various alpha reactions, but the require high energy alphas and do not have particularly high cross sections.  Getting the alpha inside the atom to make a compound nucleus is much harder that doing the same thing with a neutron (highest cross sections tend to be at low neutron energies) or gammas.

Comment: For the particular reaction, the alpha has to have an energy above 2.9MeV, and the cross section gets to about 1 millibarn at 3.6MeV. For comparison, the fission cross section for thermal neutrons on 235U exceeds 10,000 barns, so 7 orders of magnitude higher.

Comment: So the answer is that yes, technically there can be **some** induced radioactivity from alpha radiation, but practically, the amount of induced radioactivity is so low that it is considered negligible (especially when considering any potential health hazards from the level of induced radiation)? Is that essentially correct?

Comment: Yes. Further, both neutrons and gammas can go a long way in air, while even MeV alphas will only go a foot or so.

Comment: I guess it's also worth considering that P-30 has a half-life of only 2.5 minutes, so the induced radioactivity does not last for very long. I think I was just getting tripped up by what I took to be absolute statements that alpha radiation cannot induce radioactivity. It seems like from a practical standpoint (if we only care about **significant** levels of induced radioactivity) that is correct, especially when compared to the other mechanisms by which induced radioactivity occurs, but it is not technically 100% accurate.

I appreciate the response!

Comment: Note also that not all alphas are created equal. The energy matters. This is the case for calculating the reaction probability (technically, the cross section) in all nuclear reactions, but it is particularly relevant when there is a large Coulomb barrier that needs to be overcome.